# Operator not Recognized with Invoke-Expression in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the *docker* command in a PowerShell script and test if the command was not successful, but I am failing to do so. I am using:

```
if (!Invoke-Expression -Command docker ps -q -f name=php72) {
    #some other code here
}
```

The error that I get after running this is:

```
Line |
  31 |  if (!Invoke-Expression -Command docker ps -q -f name=php72) {
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term '!Invoke-Expression' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
     | path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have tried the `-not` operator to no avail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. PowerShell has 2 [parsing modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7): Expression and argument. The latter is the one where you work with commands. There, the name of the command (e.g. `Invoke-Expression`) must always come *first*.

In short: you have to *wrap* the command either with the [grouping opterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#grouping-operator--) `()` or [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#subexpression-operator--) `$()` to use it inside an expression:

```
-not (Invoke-Expression ...)
# or
-not $(Invoke-Expression ...)
```

(`-not` and `!` work exactly the [same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7))

But as @WasifHasan pointed out, docker is an *external program*, so the best way to check for success is using the `$?` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#section-1), which will be `$false` if `$LASTEXITCODE` is any other value than `0`:

```bsh
docker ps -q -f name=php72 2>&1>$null
if ($?} {
    # your other code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another bracket:

```
if (!(Invoke-Expression -Command docker ps -q -f name=php72)){
    #some other code here
}
```

Unless here `!Invoke-Expression` is evaluated, which is invalid.

Best way is to use like this:

```
docker ps -q -f name=php72 >$null 2>&1
if($lastExitCode -eq 1){"FAILED!"}
```